# Is it acceptable if I delete my answers that didn't get any response?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers, etiquette

I have this habit of deleting my answers which do not appear to get any feedback. Feedback can be either in terms of votes (up/down) or any comment or getting accepted. I usually feel that such an answer doesn't do any good and it's just another answer in the list.

Is this against the guidelines? Can this habit get me in any trouble with flags or moderator attention etc.? I'd rather not do that then. I just don't want to post or keep my ***me too*** answers. I sometimes feel any moderator might think that I'm trying to trick the system for some badges etc. That's exactly why I'm asking.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As a result of the [cc-by-sa](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) licence you have given Stack Exchange license to use and reuse that content, so in one sense the content is not yours to delete any more (that's not quite right but you (hopefully) get my drift).

We get an automatic flag when anyone deletes "too much" of their content in a short time and the mod message that we could send includes the following:

> Please note that once you post a question or answer to this site, those posts become part of the collective efforts of others who have also contributed to that content, and should not be removed except under extraordinary circumstances. Even if the post is no longer useful to the original author, that information is still beneficial to others who may run into similar problems in the future.

Having said that however, if you are deleting answers that are:

1. Zero or negative scoring.
2. On questions where there are other answers.
3. Incorrect in some way.

then we generally don't have a problem with people cleaning up their accounts.

However, if the answers aren't actually wrong - what's the problem with just leaving the answer on the site? You never know someone *might* find it useful in the future.

Comment: Not to mention, someone might upvote it some day. I've got some answers out there from two or three years ago that get the odd upvote once in a while.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher - which is what I was saying with the last sentence in the answer :)

Comment: @ChrisF Alas, if I had an upvote for every answer that was found useful, I'd be more than a 7Ker right now :)