# Do you get question bans by deleting your own posts?

Tags: support, post-ban

I have recently been question banned, probably because I keep deleting some of my answers and comments.

Sometimes, reading through a question can take a few minutes, and solving it can take another X amount of time.. by the time I comment or post an answer to the question, answers may have already been posted.

If my answer/comment is redundant, or worse than other answers/comments provided - I've been deleting my posts to reduce clutter.

**Is it better to keep redundant/worse/wrong answers/comments than to delete them?**

I've read through [Is it acceptable if I delete my answers that didn't get any response?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260298/deleting-your-answers-that-dont-get-any-response) and it doesn't really answer my question - as the questions/comments I've deleted were within 30 minutes of posting and were all 0 score or negative score.

Comment: Yes, self-deleted posts do still count in the question ban. How much the deletion *itself* weighs is not known, but I do believe it carries some weight in the formula.

Comment: Just let the community decide if your answers are 'clutter' or not through normal voting

Comment: Is there a penalty for deleting a comment?

Comment: Are you being question banned for deleting answers? I don't think it works that way. I would think you would be question banned for deleting questions.

Comment: Penalizing deleting one's own answer seems counter-productive. It encourages leaving unnecessary clutter around when two or more people type essentially the same answer at the same time.

Comment: I can understand penalizing people for deleting questions - but why answers? If you answer, and another two people had the exact same answer - with more details (or better formatted) - keeping redundant answers just seems like it'd cludder the page up.

Comment: I was told the I needed to clean up my old post for voting answer or deleting the question if no answer for a long time by someone. I did and end up to be in danger of being blocked from asking any more. it is unfair since I didn't know it would push me in this situation.

Comment: related: [How should self-deletes be evaluated in the question ban algorithm?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103670/165773) "Self-deletes already don't matter..."

Answer (score 20):

The only way to get question-banned by deleting questions is if you get in the habit of deleting them *after someone has taken the time to answer them**. This is an overtly hostile action, destroying the work that someone else has donated, and we'd just as soon the folks determined to do this left and never came back.

But apart from *that*, [the system mostly lets you delete whatever you want](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that). If you look like you're rage-quitting, a moderator may decide to have a talk with you... Otherwise, clean up after yourself and thank you for doing so!

<sup>*<sub>Sadly, this seems to happen mostly among folks trying to get their homework answered and then clean up their tracks before their professor finds out.</sub></sup>

Comment: I've deleted my own downvoted self answers, I've downvoted the answer first and then still got a warning when I've deleted the question (no other answers) is this a bad thing for zero, negative self answers?

Comment: I don't believe there are any exceptions for self-answered questions.