# Why user cannot delete their own ask question which has answered?

Tags: discussion

Why user cannot delete their own asks question which has answered? What is the logic behind this restriction.

Comment: Presumably, the SO contributors who answered would be miffed.   I guess the mods or SE staff could do it.  TBH, I would not mind having all my questions deleted - they are just targets for managed malicious downvotes:(

Comment: What type of feature are you requesting? An option for you to delete your question once answered by the help desk?

Comment: ["This is an overtly hostile action, destroying the work that someone else has donated..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311813/839601)

Comment: @gnat - Why select a duplicate target that is itself closed as a dupe? The OP here isn't asking about question bans anyway.

Comment: @MartinSmith [answer in dupe target](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/839601) covers this question by explaining why deleting answered questions is prohibited

Comment: @gnat Answer focuses on something different and tangentially has a relevant sentence stretches the definition of duplicate question to breaking point IMO.

Comment: "This (fairly rare!) pattern is seen as so overtly hostile that it does impose a pretty stiff penalty.." yeah sure, tangential

Comment: @gnat Tangential to the thrust of the answer, which is about question bans.

Comment: Generally the purpose of Stack Overflow is not just to help one person with a problem, but to help all future people with the same problem who google that problem. If you delete a question that has been adequately answered, you're denying an answer from all of those future users with the same problem coming from google search. It would be selfish to delete all of your questions as soon as they are answered, because you would be denying all future users any possibility of benefiting from the work that others put into answering your post.

Answer (score 14):

The logic behind it is that it is not possible to delete the question without also deleting the answer as collateral damage.

And that is disrespectful to the person putting effort into providing an answer, as well as potentially removing useful content.

In exceptional circumstances (e.g. posting proprietary information accidentally) you can flag and ask if a moderator would consider deleting it. Or you can ask for your account to be disassociated with a question - e.g. if it is particularly embarrassing for some reason.