# Why can't I delete the question (posted by me)?

Tags: discussion

Why can't I delete the question (posted by me) if the question has answers?

I get the "Sorry this question has answer and cannot be deleted" message.

As it is posted by me, I should be allowed to delete it.

Comment: related: [Do you get question bans by deleting your own posts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311813/839601) "The only way to get question-banned by deleting questions is if you get in the habit of deleting them *after someone has taken the time to answer them*. This is an overtly hostile action, destroying the work that someone else has donated, and we'd just as soon the folks determined to do this left and never came back..."

Comment: Look at the flip side.  Why do you get to delete answers that other people posted?  With your reasoning it is there answer and they should be able to have it out there.

Answer (score 14):

When posting on here, you license the post and all of its contents irrevocably to Stack Exchange under the [CC BY SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license. That means that you cannot freely remove your post. You may request that it be disassociated from your account via a custom moderator flag, but you may not delete it once it has gotten answers.

Deleting your own questions after people have taken the time to answer them is disrespectful and unsavory.

Comment: I agree, but what when the question has been flagged as duplicate and the answer isn't good at all ?

Comment: @SuperPeanut other users with sufficient reputation are able to cast delete votes to remove such posts.

Comment: OK then I totally agree...

Comment: @SuperPeanut - Also, if there's only one answer and it has no up votes you are still able to delete the question.