# Why can we delete our own answers but not questions that we posted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

Recently I came across a situation where in the there are couple of answers which have got more than 10 upvotes were deleted. I believe that the users who might have posted the answer could have deleted them or by reputed users with > 20k (correct me If I am wrong).

I am trying to understand the reason for "why not delete the question that is posted by us if we can do for the posted answer?

From this [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322395/why-cant-i-delete-the-question-posted-by-me),

> Deleting your own questions after people have taken the time to answer
>   them is disrespectful and unsavory.

Does the same thing apply to the posted answer as it is read and upvoted by many?

Comment: `Does the same thing apply to the posted answer as it is read and upvoted by many?` um... no? A question is a request to others to contribute and spend time and energy. An answer *is* a contribution of time and energy. Different things, no?

Comment: Answers can only be delete when they are at -1 or lower: https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers and needs 3 voters. also for that link: *Answers can be deleted at any time by their authors, unless the answer has been accepted by the question asker.*. Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Deleting the question deletes all the answers to it - those answers are other people's work. Deleting your answer only deletes your own work.

Having said that...

- if an answer is accepted you can't delete it (only a moderator or a group of 3 other 20K rep users can).
- if a question has no answers or a single answer with no upvotes you can still delete it
- answers can become obsolete as technology changes. The answerer may be aware of that without knowing how to update it. An upvoted answer may have had an early life getting a steady stream of upvotes and now gets a steady stream of downvotes. The answerer will be more aware of that than you are when you simply look at the answers total score although you can look at the annswer's timeline to find out.
- it's possible that answers are wrong and still get upvoted. The wisdom of crowds is good but not infallible.
- the question may have changed. Normally one would roll this back if it invalidated the answer but I have seen questions where there's an answer to the original question and one or more answers to the edited question and deleting something may be the best course of action to fix the mess.

Comment: On some tags, answers that are absolutely and completely wrong, and cannot possibly work, get upvoted and accepted,  (yes, I'm referring to [multithreading])  :(