# Can I get a question ban from revenge downvotes?

Tags: discussion

I've answered 184 questions on SO, with varying but mostly successful results.  But I've only ever asked three questions, two of which had zero total votes (up or down) for almost all of their existence.

Two weeks ago, I significantly stepped up my participation in the moderation of SO.  I have started casting more close votes, and I have also been "posting" comments as a function of participating in the VLQ review queue.  About the same time, I started receiving downvotes on a question that has seen **no activity since July 2015**.  I know there's a chance it could just be coincidence, but I very much doubt it.

I know there's really nothing I can do about those downvotes.  People won't attack my *answers* because it costs them rep.  Downvoting my *questions* will never be detected as serial downvoting, because I just don't have enough questions to make a pattern.  But still, even a single up or downvote is very significant in low-traffic tags.  It's certainly not hurting my rep all that much, but it is hurting my total question score.  My question here is **Because I have so few question *upvotes*, can revenge downvotes cause me to get a question ban?**

Like I said, I'm perfectly willing to shrug off the rep drain as cost of moderating the site.  But if trying to make the site better by using the moderation functions is going to cost me the ability to post questions, then it's not worth it.

*<s>As an aside, because that question gathered so little interest, I'm already at a net negative rep for having posted it.  From a purely game theory perspective, am I better off just deleting the question and the upvoted answers that go with it, in order to stop people from downvoting me?</s>* **EDIT**: Please disregard this last paragraph. I see now deleting a question with upvoted answers is never a good idea (if even possible).  This fits in with my original intuition that removing good content doesn't benefit the site.

Comment: You can't delete a question with upvoted or multiple answers.

Comment: Don't delete the question. If the votes weren't justified, they won't be there for long.

Comment: You only have three downvotes in total on your questions. And many more upvotes, there's no problem. Also you edit to your question invalidates most of my answer ;) not a good idea http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290297/how-much-change-to-the-question-is-too-much

Comment: @Yvette Two weeks ago, I had 6 upvotes and 0 downvotes across all of my questions.  Two hours ago, I had 6 and 3.  You understand my concern?  Any change since then is attributable to the meta effect, though invoking that was not my intent.

Comment: Having a couple of questions around to act as a lightning rod is a good practice.  *Everybody* that answers questions get retaliatory DVs, all of Jon Skeet's top questions have multiple DVs for example.  Incompetent programmers look for somebody to blame when they can't complete a simple task and you are the first candidate.  No need to worry about bans at all, you have a lot of positive scoring contributions.  Jon Skeet isn't going to get question-banned either :)

Comment: Three downvotes is nothing to worry about - and as Hans says, especially not for someone with your track record.

Comment: You can also ask the SO support for disconnecting your question(s) from your account. That question(s) will then be assigned to an "anon" account and it will be gone from your profile. If the revenge downvotes are keep comming and you prefer to keep the questions, because they are good, then this is a possible way. The vote score on these questions will stay, though.

Comment: Similar question from a while back: [What's wrong with this question of mine and what can I do about it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194290)

Comment: @Tom Then the revenge downvoters will just move on to the next question. Also, I wouldn't be surprised if dissociated questions still counted towards a ban.

Comment: @S.L.Barth actually that would be interesting to know http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281136/do-questions-disassociated-from-an-account-count-towards-a-question-ban

Comment: @S.L.Barth Yes, then you're heavily targeted, then you end up with no more questions, but I guess that's better than having each question downvoted into oblivion.

Comment: Ironically, just got a spate of downvotes since answering this and I've been making some more comments on posts.

Comment: Side note: getting multiple ongoing downvotes on fixed number of questions requires voting ring - so if you actually see such pattern it is good time to raise moderator tag. Otherwise [honeypot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeypot_(computing)) question is a safe place for people to express they disagreement as @HansPassant pointed out.

Comment: *"Can I get a question ban from revenge downvotes?"* - Hmmm at first I thought you're the one taking revenge :P Came here for something interesting but...

Answer (score 21):

As for deleting the question. It's unwise (if not impossible) to delete a question with answers on it ([How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that))  , especially upvoted answers and this can result in post bans and you are more likely to get a question ban from this.

> [The only way to get question-banned by deleting questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311813/3956566) is if you get in the habit of deleting them after someone has taken the time to answer them*. This is an overtly hostile action, destroying the work that someone else has donated, and we'd just as soon the folks determined to do this left and never came back.

I have an accepted answer to a question that has so many mixed votes on it, I'd like to delete it and I cannot, as it's the accepted answer, likewise I have an off topic question with downvotes and I would like to delete it, but it has an upvoted answer on it, so I cannot. So perhaps leave it be for now, see how things unravel and move on.

Also deleting the question makes no difference for the likelihood of receiving bans, it's the number of downvotes that will bring that about, and deleting a question with upvoted answers. [I apparently got question-banned for deleting some of my old, zero-upvoted questions.  Is there a better way to handle these?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91956/i-apparently-got-question-banned-for-deleting-some-of-my-old-zero-upvoted-quest)

Given your rep and site participation, it's unlikely  you'll be receiving a question ban any time soon.

This is possible revenge downvoting, but impossible to definitively say yes or no. Definitely leaving comments and being active on meta and the review queues does draw attention to a user's activity and find myself following threads of interests that may start from a comment and I look at a user's posts, for both positive and negative reasons. I may be impressed with someone's knowledge or appalled by someone's attitude.

This is also a reason I don't comment as often when reviewing on the queues [Are other reviewers opting to use no comment to avoid confrontation and is this a problem?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313992/are-other-reviewers-opting-to-use-no-comment-to-avoid-confrontation-and-is-this), whatever they be. I've had a couple of spates of revenge downvotes, but they've been so obvious, they were automatically reversed with the script.

If you suspect serial (or revenge) downvoting that is not reversed make a custom mod flag saying why. I find they have always been good for replying to these and investigate it.

> [**What if I think I'm the victim of voting fraud?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/310756)
>
> If the voting fraud is in the progress of happening or just happened recently, don't worry about it. You should wait at least 24 hours after noticing before becoming concerned. The system should detect it and reverse it for you. Please do not try to get help on this issue on meta or by flagging for a moderator. All they will do is tell you to wait for the voting fraud script to run (they won't run it for you just this once).
>
> If the 24 hours has already passed and the suspicious votes have not been reversed, you can then flag one of your posts and explain what happened so a moderator can look into it. It is generally preferred that you avoid asking about them on a site's Meta since details of the investigation cannot be divulged and you won't actually get any information that will be useful to other members of the community.

Comment: ok it's finished, after misreading initial question and taking 5 years to find links and 552,361 edits, it's done. In the old days it would've been converted to a community wiki by now.

Comment: Even in ye olde days, it took a lot more than 4 revisions to convert a post into community wiki. But yes, ye olde timers got ye olde tired of this.

Comment: Back in my day we didn't have the fancy computer-ma-jiggers. *shakes fist* These darn kids catchin' them Poké-mans on my lawn need to get a job.

Comment: @James at least they are not catching frogs.

Comment: @simbabque back in my day we collected tadpoles and waited. *this generation can't wait for a cheese burger*