# delete own question after finding solution that also answers another (earlier) question?

Tags: discussion

I was unable to apply [an accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38192821/4798582) to my problem. After working on my issue for some time I posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38871657/4798582), explaining the subject and also linking to the accepted answer. My question basically asks the same question, but because the other question had an accepted answer, I thought that my problem was  a different one.

After another hour, I finally found a solution to my problem. I think that the solution that I found

1. answers [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38871657/4798582)
2. answers [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38192733/4798582) for which I could not apply the accepted answer to my problem.

For now I have entered the solution that I found as edit to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38871657/4798582), and I have added an answer to the [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38192733/4798582) (from which I could not apply the accepted solution to my case).

I was thinking of deleting [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38871657/4798582). If I do not delete my question it will appear as unanswered duplicate although I found a solution and the question originally was not a duplicate. And if I provide and accept an answer to my own question, there will be the same answer to two apparently identical questions. Is my reasoning correct and should I delete my question?

---

P.S., I do by no means want to imply that the initial accepted answer to the other question did not help the OP. It simply did not work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't looked at the question in depth, but it seems you asked a good question and showed research.

Since you posted your answer on the other question, you could vote to close your question as a duplicate of that one.

I see no reason to delete the question. Duplicate questions aren't a problem; they just help to drive more searchers to the right answer.
As a side note, if you delete a question of your own that already has an answer, [that counts towards a question ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311813/812149).

The alternative would have been to post the answer to your own question, which is also fine. Since you already posted it on the other question, I suggest you just leave it at that.

Comment: @Flo ...and please don't edit the solution into the question. Questions are questions and answers are answers and should not be mixed.

Comment: Deleted questions don't count against you for the question ban, they just don't make that question stop being considered by the algorithm.  It's affect on whether or not you can ask questions is exactly the same whether it's deleted or not.

Comment: @Servy Makes sense; do you have a reference for that? I can't seem to find one.

Comment: I don't have a link off of the top of my head, but it's been mentioned numerous times.

Comment: Marked my question as duplicate. @piet.t thanks, I removed the answer that I had entered as edit into my question.