# Should I save my reputation, or let it be?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, answers, accepted-answer

So I have this question on Stack Overflow [asking for certain differences of C#'s floating-point values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65057248/what-is-the-difference-between-16-bit-32-bit-64-bit-and-128-bit-floating-point).

It was a poor question, as the downvotes were added. I didn't care about the votes, but what I had in mind was getting rep by accepting [phuclv's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65057248/what-is-the-difference-between-16-bit-32-bit-64-bit-and-128-bit-floating-point/65057411#65057411), as it really helped me from building my project (which I won't reveal).

Sadly, the rep is always taken away. I accepted his answer when the question was at a score of -3. I later come back at the site and the 3 rep went back to 1 because the score is already -5. I unaccepted it and waited for a while, while I continue with my program.

I come back to the site and nothing happened, so I reaccepted the answer. Some time later, the score went to -6 (as of the making of this question). So I unaccepted it again.

Here is my question. Should I leave this question as it is and accept the answer?

> I will need the rep so I can talk on the meta of SO.

Comment: Your own answer to the question (now deleted) got a downvote.  Does that play a role?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q Nope. The question is the only one. Not everyone can even see that answer. Also, the answer was only deleted when the question was at a score of -3.

Comment: With [20,482,906 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) (1,449,687 in the C# tag) there is a fair chance such a question has already been asked.

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q That makes sense. After all, there is already a question asking the differences of these types with the [tag:.net] tag. Mine only revolves on C# and even with the 16-bit floating-point.

Comment: @HenryWillies You can always ask about your own questions on SO on Meta SO. So you don't need the rep from accepting an answer for that. As for the rest, just accepting one answer doesn't get you the reputation you need anyways, so better see if you can improve your question or write a good answer to another question, as that'll get you to your goal sooner.

Comment: I think the moment the accepted answer starts with "Why don't just check the official documents?" probably led people to downvote for lack of research.

Comment: @Henry - Why did you unaccept and reaccept the answer though?  You lose the reputation you earned from accepting the answer when you unaccept the answer.  Your reputation is a summation of all votes.  So your actions didn’t do anything

Comment: @SecurityHound Here is the summary. My rep turned 1 after someone downvoted, so I unaccepted the answer for some time. I came back and reaccepted it, giving me +2 rep. If it might happen again, I do it again, until I asked this question. I let it be.

Comment: @HenryWillies - If you have multiple downvotes on the question, accepting the answer, will still result in you having 1 reputation.  If for some reason, your reputation actually does increase, then that actually is a bug that should be reported.

Comment: @SecurityHound there is no "memory" for negative votes - so if one moves positive reputation change to happen *after* all negative once then only positive change will count (i.e. on first question: -1,-1, accept, -1, -1 = 1rep, -1,-1,-1,-1, accept = 3rep)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov True. I discovered this trick on getting back to 3 rep this way.

Comment: @HenryWillies No pays much attention if you got 1 or 3 points and you'd get more points if you spend your time editing posts for example... Also it really does not matter for the site what reputation you got from the point  of the question ban to which your account is already well on the way too... If you plan to ask more question on SO I'd strongly recommend reading https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th *before* that happen.

Comment: Your next question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65087975/what-does-empty-divs-do is also bad.  There is no point in asking "I'm curious why these tags are here for whatever reason.".  Only the developers at Google can answer that and it's probably some trivial reason too.

Comment: @JK. You can just edit it out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reputation is easy to come by.  You can get an upvote and you'll be essentially back in the black, as it were.

What I'd concern myself *more* with is the quality filter.  Questions that aren't well received - like this one - will contribute to a question ban.  Deleting it doesn't help that issue, either; if anything, it actually makes it worse.

There's not likely much you can do to rescue this question, so it's probably wise to [take the L](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Take%20the%20L) here and let it be.

Comment: Yeah, they're probably gonna end my question there. One more delete vote and the question's dead.

Comment: Shog9 has stated that deleting your question after it has received an answer is [considered by the system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311813/3773011) as ["overtly hostile"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/3773011). It's believed to be one of the worst things you can do with respect to getting a question ban.

Comment: It's their decision. I can't change it.