# I wish to delete my own answer but a Mod just undeleted it. Do I have any rights, here?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers

I have an answer which I wish to delete. I wrote it a while ago.

I have enough points to do this, and I did do this. I just noticed that a mod recently undeleted that post.

Does this mean that I've got no rights to the content I provide here? Is there something on page 10000 of the Terms of Service or something which would say I have no rights?

Please, I'm not trying to start a war or get people in trouble or anything like that.

Do I have delete-rights here over a mod with respect to my own content?

The answer I posted is on Stack Overflow, which was why I'm asking here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing Under subscriber content

Comment: _"Apologies if this is the wrong site to ask these meta q's, on."_ I believe you're on the correct site

Comment: Some people tried to mass-delete their content out of spite. This "undelete" permission has helped the community a few times, so it's not only legal but a good thing.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers. Really appreciate it. Basically this: "are the property of Stack Overflow". I own nothing. I provide answers and it's not mine. no probs, ta!

Comment: Note: I believe I found the answer you are talking about, just some frank advice, deleting an answer that 150+ users found useful because someone edited and removed some jokes / memes from your post seems like a hasty decision.

Comment: *" I own nothing. I provide answers and it's not mine. no probs, ta!"* This isn't correct; for example you still own the copyright of your content, no [so].

Comment: I don't understand @ThomA -> "everything is the property of SO" ... so they have ownership over it?

Comment: Also - why the downvotes? How I asked the question? the core topic of the question?

Comment: You may be experiencing some meta down-votes for the comment, "*no probs, ta!*". It's not like we who monitor the meta site and try to help folks with meta questions are the ones who are responsible for what you're experiencing on the site. We're site volunteers who are just trying to explain things as best we can, and it's as if you're blowing off the helpful comments made here for no reason and in an unprofessional way. You may want to delete that comment.

Comment: *"You agree that any and all content, including without limitation any and all text ... that you provide to the public Network (collectively, “Subscriber Content”), is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Overflow on a worldwide"* nowhere does it state your content is property of [so]. Licenced to <> Owned by.

Comment: You can flag to get the content disassociated from your account. The post would remain, but you would have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Oh... all this over an edit war because another user was removing memes and so forth. Sad. Well, we do hate fun here. But why delete an otherwise excellent answer, just because it does not include enough animated gifs and unicorn pictures?

Comment: The question is so different that I don't think this qualifies as a dupe, but the answer is completely relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260303/1426539. Again, if you simply want to be done with the post, just flag to disassociate yourself from it.

Comment: thanks again everyone for the answers. Really appreciate it. Question has been answered

Comment: "Do I have delete-rights here over a mod with respect to my own content?" - It really depends.  If the answer was determined to be unhelpful you should really improve the answer.  If the answer was determined to be helpful, the answer absolutely, should not be deleted. If you need something retracted from the answer that can be done. What will not be allowed, is for you to delete a helpful answer, because you found an edit proposal to be unacceptable. Deleting contribution, because you disagree with something that community did, is one of those most toxic behaviors that exist on this platform.

Comment: "Is there something on page 10000 of the Terms of Service or something which would say I have no rights?" "Please, I'm not trying to start a war or get people in trouble or anything like that." The tone of the first statement is incompatible with the claim of the second.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The [irrevocable CC BY-SA license](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing) that you submitted your post under (see also footer) gives Stack Exchange the right to display your post on the site forever. Moderators are therefore empowered to undelete posts that they feel should not have been deleted—there is even a flag raised automatically when a number of posts are quickly deleted to help them keep on top of this.

You do own the content, and can do what you like with it elsewhere, including republishing, modifying, or further licensing it.

Comment: I would add that, in fact, regular users are also empowered to undelete posts (assuming it was not originally deleted by a mod).

Comment: Hm, that is a nice distinction. You own the content, but you do not own the database record.